# display comments in a python script

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, comments

Is there a way, beside parsing the file, to display the comments in a Python file ?
As in :

```
d = {
    # key value uses
    k = v
}
```

I would display :

```
# key value uses
```

in the function `__doc__`.

Thanks

Comment: I think only using docstrings

Comment: docstrings are ignored if not just after the function definition, aren't they ?

Comment: @JohnDoe: yes, and comments are always deleted. So you'll have to parse the source yourself if you want them.

Comment: @rici thanks, I will accept as an answer if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python  always deletes (and docstrings not at the beginning of a definition). So you'll have to parse the source yourself if you want to extract them.

The standard library's `ast` module also drops comments, but you could take a look at the [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) module, which returns them. (However, it doesn't parse, so you'd still need to do some work to associate the comment with its function or class or whatever.)